# Pure DQL vs DQB?

Tags: symfony

Can someone elaborate performance of DQL and DQL? I am comfortable with both but concerned if there is some performance issues? 
In short,

Which one is faster performance wise,  Doctrine Query Language or Doctrine Query Builder?

Comment: Hi Stocker, I asked general question to stick with one approach to query db. Just for consistency sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DQL is faster because the QueryBuilder is a step to build a DQL query.

Only use QueryBuilder if your query needs to be "built" (adding terms depending on some logic)